# How to download file from DigitalOcean App platform to local system?

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean, strapi, digital-ocean-apps

I have a Strapi app hosted on digitalocean App Platform. I exported its data to a .tar file and want to download it to my local system, but Im not sure how to.

I tried using running SCP:

scp -r  root@:/root/my-strapi-export.tar.gz Documents/export.tar.gz
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection timed out
scp: Connection closed

Comment: Are you able to SSH to that system?

Comment: I think it's unlikely that you can SSH into an instance of a DigitalOcean App. How were you able to export the data? From some in-app functionality? Is it possible there's some way you can use HTTP to `GET` the tar file?